# How to call wordpress plugin function with ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

i want to make a wordpress plugin.

But i want to learn, plugin admin panel how to click and run function.

same page if you click link call function but same page ajax.

like this

```
<a href='javascript:void(0); class="btn2"'>

function examplefunc() {
echo 'say hello':

}
```

this is easy example. same page if click btn2 class call examplefunc

How to make this thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call java script function in hyperlink then below is the simple example;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(myMessage) {
    alert(myMessage);
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:myFunction('You clicked!')">My link</a>
```

Simple WordPress Ajax Example: https://gist.github.com/devinsays/69a305053e35a10584f94d6011bba2d6